# python move folder contents without moving the source folder

Tags: python, shutil

shutil.move(src, dst) is what I feel will do the job, however, as per the  [python 2 document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html):

> shutil.move(src, dst) Recursively move a file or directory (src) to
>   another location (dst).
>
> If the destination is an existing directory, then src is moved inside
>   that directory. If the destination already exists but is not a
>   directory, it may be overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.

This is a little bit different than my case as below:

Before the move:
https://snag.gy/JfbE6D.jpg

```
shutil.move(staging_folder, final_folder)
```

After the move:

https://snag.gy/GTfjNb.jpg

This is not what I want, I want all the content in the staging folder be moved over to under folder "final" , I don't need "staging" folder itself.

It would be greatly appreciated if you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the path was not correct because it contains \t which was misinterpreted.

I ended up using shutil.move + shutil.copy22

```
for i in os.listdir(staging_folder):
    if not os.path.exists(final_folder):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(staging_folder, i), final_folder)
    else:
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(staging_folder, i), final_folder)
```

and then emptify the old folder:

```
def emptify_staging(self, folder):
    for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
                # elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `shutil.copytree()` to move all contents in *staging_folder* to *final_folder* without moving the *staging_folder* . Pass the argument `copy_function=shutil.move` when calling the function.

For Python 3.8:

```
shutil.copytree('staging_folder', 'final_folder', copy_function=shutil.move, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

For Python 3.7 and below:

beware that the paramater `dirs_exist_ok` is not supported. The destination *final_folder* **must not already exist** as it will be created during moving.

```
shutil.copytree('staging_folder', 'final_folder', copy_function=shutil.move)
```

### Example code (Python 3.8):

```
>>> os.listdir('staging_folder')
['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

>>> os.listdir('final_folder')
[]

>>> shutil.copytree('staging_folder', 'final_folder', copy_function=shutil.move, dirs_exist_ok=True)
'final_folder'

>>> os.listdir('staging_folder')
[]

>>> os.listdir('final_folder')
['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os.listdir` and then move each file to the required destination.

**Ex:**

```
import shutil
import os

for i in os.listdir(staging_folder):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(staging_folder, i), final_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't move the sub folder in staging